# Text-Field Nib after Tap (IOS5)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, uitextfield

I am developing an application for **iOS 5**.

I am trying to push a nib after tapping on a text-field to add an item and pull down the current screen. When I attach the following code to a button, it works:

`-(IBAction)addView:(id)sender` on touch-up

Unfortunately - when I do something similar on a textField, I do not get the same result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can also consider to put a transparent button over the textField and give it the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to push a nib file on tap of your `UITextFeild` you need to use the delegate method of textfield

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Now what you need t o do is push your view as below :

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
         ViewController  *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
return  NO;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can 
use the below delegate of textField and write your own conditions for the functionality

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

return NO for not showing the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use TextField's Delegate and set your textfieldDelegate = self:

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {  
    //Your code to push nib
    return NO 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
         //Push your view here 
}
```